# How to access data in System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, reflection

I'm trying to learn how to access data in a `System.Object`.  There's a Visual Studio 2015 c# .net application which calls a Matlab function using the following code:

```
object result = null;

matlab.Feval("matlabTest", 1, out result);
```

If I hover over the variable `result` when debugging it shows up as 
`result|{object[1]}`.  If I slide down to further expand `result` it shows up as `[0]:{object[53,13]}`.  Then when sliding down further I can see the two dimensional array of strings and doubles.  So, the debugger can see and display the valid data in "result" but I have no idea how to access the strings and doubles at runtime.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to cast the result to the correct type. E.g. `var x = (YourType)result`

Comment: I don't know how to determine what YourType is and it can change at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, you need to do something like the following:

```
object[] first_array = (object[])result;

object[,] second_array = (object[,])first_array[0];
```

And then access the second array like this:

```
var item = second_array[5,5];
```

Another approach is to use the [dynamic keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) like this:

```
dynamic dynamic_result = result;

var test_value = dynamic_result[0][5, 5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always call `<variable>.GetType()` to see which type it is and then cast it based on this information.

Answer (score -1):

an easy way to get access to object, is use typeof() to get it type, and use Reflection to access its data.

Comment: The type is object[].  How can I use Reflection to access object[]?

Comment: if it's a array, try typeof(result[0]) to get it real type.

Comment: Oh, I see it's a 1d-array points to another 2d array. use type(result[0][0,0]) to get the real type.

Comment: `typeof` is used for getting a `Type` object that represents a type *statically specified at compile time*.  You have to *already know the type* in order to use `typeof`.